# How to reopen dialog, that was closed with EndDialog(); in C

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, dialog

I am making a simple program to control Android device via ADB.
And when I need to open ADB Shell, I need to close dialog. But actually I don't know how to reopen it.
I am closing Dialog before opening ADB Shell, but I need to reopen it when ADB shell will be closed.
My "code":

```
BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        g_hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));

        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)LoadIcon(NULL,
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION)));
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)LoadIcon(NULL,
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION)));
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:
        return (LONG)g_hbrBackground;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        SetBkMode(hdcStatic, TRANSPARENT);
        return (LONG)g_hbrBackground;
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDADBSHELL:
            if (file_exist("bin\\adb.exe"))
            {
                EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
                system("cmd /c echo 'To exit type 'exit'' & timeout /T 10 & bin\\adb.exe shell & pause");
                // Now need to open Dialog again
                break;
            }
            EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"adb.exe was not found!", L"Error",
                MB_OK);
            DeleteObject(MessageBox);
            exit(1);
            break;
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(g_hbrBackground);
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DlgProc);
}
```

I am closing Dialog before opening ADB Shell, but I need to reopen it when ADB shell will be closed.

P.S. Removed some unneccessary information (such as another buttons, that do nothing, includes)

Comment: Have `WinMain` call `DialogBox` multiple times in a loop. Use the return value to decide that the dialog does not need to be re-spawned and it's time to break out of that loop.

Comment: Something like... s/`system("cmd /c echo 'To exit type 'exit''`/`puts("To exit, type 'exit'");`/; s/`& timeout /T 10 & bin\\adb.exe shell`/`CreateProcess(TEXT("bin\\adb.exe"), TEXT("shell"), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInformation); Sleep(10000); TerminateProcess(ProcessInformation.hProcess, 0); puts("Press any key to continue"); getchar();`/???

Comment: @Seb &StartupInfo, &ProcessInformation, ProcessInformation are undefined. It seems I need some headers...

Comment: Well, yes, you need some headers and some declarations. I expect that you know how to declare `StartupInfo` and `ProcessInformation`; if you don't, you should be reading a book to learn C rather than using the Win32 API which assumes you already know C.

Comment: All of the information you need to include the required headers and declare the required variables is available at [this manual here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)... You might even find a full example, if you read carefully.